# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server unable to boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, server, grub2

My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server is unable to boot. when I power on the machine, it starts briefly but then shuts down immediately and powers on again but in a repeat cycle. Initially, I thought its some sort of hardware failure but ruled that out as I am able to boot using Ubuntu live USB.
I have checked all hardware and disks and they seem to be working fine. I started my server using ubuntu live USB and managed to do boot-repair but when trying to boot from harddisk it follows the pattern mentioned above like start -> shutdown -> start.
Please check the boot-repair log at link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Wjp4BtFqYz/
At this stage I am unable to figure out the issue and appreciate any sort of direciton.
If any more information is required please let me know.

Last actions which I performed where moving the docker installation files from root partition to another partition where I have enough space (this was due to fact that docker was using lot of space on root)

Thank you in advance
Rahul

Latest update
I have done the memtest+86 V5.31b and no errors were reported. Also the /var/log/dmesg did not have any entries. I then moved my all docker files back to original location (this was the last step I did after which the server failed to boot) so in short reversed my last action and finally server was able to boot but the load was too high and it was running extremly slowly. I looked at the processes using TOP and found zoneminder was taking too much of CPU so removed it completely. now the server is starting and running smoothly. I have no explanation as why was server starting and stopping when I was trying to boot initially but something seems to have fixed it. I also noticed that the boot partition is away (>100gb) from the start of the disk, could that be a problem? after I did the boot-repair fix, I think the grub is now installed on the first drive rather than the dedicated partition which is 100gb away. Thank you all for assissting with this issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome. It certainly sounds like a hardware issue. How you done a ram test and a hard drive test? BTW on the 22 nd of this month 16.04 is out of standard support. What that means is no more questions can be asked here about that version. You will also not get any more patches or updates. You can get ESM support but you would not be able to ask questions here. Time to think about an upgrade.

Comment: @David This also sounds like a software issue.

My laptop used to do this when my bootloader was messed up somehow. One time it was because I got a BSOD in Windows, and it corrupted my bootloader. The other time was when I swapped my drives around and GRUB could no longer locate the correct `/efi` partition. If you can, on a separate booting OS, install a new bootloader like `rEFInd` to rule this out.

Comment: Thanks for your responses @David & MaybeLBDidIt. I will perform the memtest and post back my findings. Also I only have Ubuntu installed on my server so no dual boot. do you still suggest I use refind for booting?

Comment: I have updated my findings in my original post

Answer (score 0):

When you mount the broken system's storage, have a look at `/var/log/dmesg` in there to see if there's any obvious indication what's happening at boot time.